# Connecting android_tutorial_pubsub from Android device to PC

Tags: ubuntu, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't seem to connect to the PC from an Android device running android_tutorial_pubsub.

I changed it so that android_tutorial_pubsub is not running it's own ROS master as per:
http://answers.ros.org/question/30726/does-android_tutorial_pubsub-connect-to-other-ros

I use ifconfig to get the IP on the Ubuntu VM (running on a Mac), but when I ping that address from adb shell, it says that it's unreachable.

Also, adb logcat tells me:

E/Registrar(21222): Exception caught while communicating with master.
I/DefaultPublisher(21222): Publisher registration failed: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeSlaveIdentifier</android_gingerbread/ros_text_view, [http://192.168.0.116:42837>](http://192.168.0.116:42837%3E), TopicIdentifier>, TopicDefinition<TopicIdentifier, MessageDefinition<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>

Am I missing a step somewhere or using the wrong URI?

Edit: I've seen posts about setting ROS_IP and I tried that too (set in .bashrc).

Edit: The problem was with VMWare Fusion.  It was a networking setting.  In VMWare, select the wrench icon for the VM, then choose "Network Adaptor" and then "Connect Directly to the Physical Network (Bridged)".  Now I can ping and the publisher on the android device can send to the ros master on the VM.  Yay!

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31031/connecting-android_tutorial_pubsub-from-android-device-to-pc/) by [amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2073/amigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @amigo:
The problem was with VMWare Fusion. It was a networking setting. In VMWare, select the wrench icon for the VM, then choose "Network Adaptor" and then "Connect Directly to the Physical Network (Bridged)". Now I can ping and the publisher on the android device can send to the ros master on the VM. Yay!

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2012-04-04**:
Amigo, could you mark the question as answered by selecting this answer as correct?